# Heroku server not loading tailwind css styles with my laravel project

Tags: laravel, heroku, deployment, tailwind-css, production

I deployed Laravel with Tailwind css on Heroku and my vanilla CSS for the home page is working fine but when I add /login to the address to move to laravel breeze login page, Tailwind css isn't loading.

This is the link for the homepage: https://zarafah.herokuapp.com/

And this is the login page which tailwind is not rendering: https://zarafah.herokuapp.com/login

When i checked the network tap on google chrome it shows like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pbqoo.png)

This is driving me crazy because on my local serve everything works perfectly.

I ran npm run prod and npm run production and made sure of everything but still I can't find out what is the issue.

I'm using Laravel 8 with Tailwind css v3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a http link for the css

change it to https

https://zarafah.herokuapp.com/css/app.css

and it should work